# Google Places API key expires running after once

Tags: google-places-api

I just created a project in Google Places API and got a key.I tried one of their sample query in the browser. It worked fine once. But as soon as I run it again, I get below error

```
{
   "error_message" : "You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API. If you did not set a custom daily request quota, verify your project has an active billing account: http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account",
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "status" : "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"
}
```

That seems odd. What am I missing?

Comment: "If you did not set a custom daily request quota, verify your project has an active billing account: http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account" We're assuming you already have an active billing account?

Comment: adding a billing account resolved this. This seems to be a new thing with Google. Didn't need to setup the billing account ~6 months back.

Comment: Was it the same query twice, any changes? Google's error messages aren't friendly and I thought this one looked familiar, my issue was an unescaped character: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42500337/google-translate-service-account-403-dailylimitexceeded-error

Comment: @stealththeninja it was a different query.

Comment: and if you run the working query again,does it work again or same error? We can also move this to private chat if it becomes a troubleshooting conversation.

Comment: @stealththeninja yes same error. But as I mentioned, adding a billing account resolved it.

Comment: Sorry, wasn’t clear that adding a billing account resolved the issue. Mind answering your own question for the next person?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after I'd used my Places API key for quite a bit, have you been using the key for a while now? Maybe the total number of requests per day are restricted beyond a certain limit. I believe they have weekly quotas as well.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a billing account resolved it.